# Kafka Streams detecting missing records

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm building a streaming app via Kafka Streams 2.10 and I'm facing a conceptual issue.

```
The producer1 sends (Key -> Value): Session1 -> RUNNING

The producer2 sends (Key -> Value): Sessionabc -> RUNNING

The producer1 sends (Key -> Value): Session1 -> DONE
```

Now I want to detect a dead session. I'm trying to use a SessionWindow but because Kafka computes record by record I cannot calculate all at once.

Here is my snippet:

```java
builder
    .stream("topic", Consumed.with(serdeKeySessionEvent, serdeValueSessionEvent))
    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(serdeKeySessionEvent, serdeValueSessionEvent))
    .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(SESSION_DURATION))
    .reduce(new SessionReducer())
    .toStream((windowed, value) -> windowed.key())
    .filter((k,v)-> Objects.nonNull(v) && v.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING)
    .peek((a,b)->System.out.println("This Value is missing: \n   "+a.toString()+b.toString()));`
```

Note: The reducer just makes sure that when we see a DONE regardless which other element we have for the same session it will be always done. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: I might be better to use the Processor API instead of the DSL for this use case.

Comment: Can you elaborate a Little more ? Why is the one better than the other ?

Comment: It's more flexible. The DSL offers pre-defined operator semantics that don't meet your requirements and it seem hard to "bend" them for your use case.

Comment: @JorgeMachado, what do you mean by dead session? Those one, which didn't send **RUNNING** for a _long_ time without sending **DONE**?

Comment: @wardziniak exactly. I need to detect this case and perform some cleanup action. This means for a giving window and a given key I need to get a list of all elements and if there is no done there the session is basically dead

Comment: @wardziniak Ping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Processor API it can be done easily with a little more of code. DSL can be mixed with Processor API.

Processing would look like this.

1. Build state store and add it using `StreamsBuilder::addStateStore`
2. Create KStream and call `KStream::transform` function with Transformer, that do whole work
3. Result of transform will be messages with information if session is **DEAD** or **DONE**
4. Using Transformer you implement how each message should be processed. For each message you have to update keyValue Store, where key is session Id. You have to save timestamp of last message regarding the session
5. Then in Punctuator (that is called periodically), you check which session are TIMEOUT, and pass information, using `ProcessorContext::forward` with status (DONE, DEAD)

Whole code how to do that, you can found [here](https://github.com/wardziniak/kafka-tutorial/blob/master/kafka-streams/src/main/java/com/wardziniak/kafka/streams/apps/missing_records/DetectMissingRecordApp.java)

Comment: This seems to be it. I will test it in 3 days and let you know. Thanks a lot for the code. Nice !